# How to Convert 6 sec Power Consumption Time Series Data To 1 Hour Data?

Tags: python, pandas, energy

I have a Time Series Data-set that looks like the following:

```
Dates           Power
09-11-12 23:40  123
09-11-12 23:40  0
09-11-12 23:40  0
09-11-12 23:40  0
09-11-12 23:40  0
09-11-12 23:40  123
09-11-12 23:40  123
09-11-12 23:40  122
09-11-12 23:40  122
09-11-12 23:41  122
09-11-12 23:41  0
09-11-12 23:41  0
09-11-12 23:41  161
09-11-12 23:41  123
09-11-12 23:41  124
09-11-12 23:41  123
09-11-12 23:41  123
09-11-12 23:41  123
09-11-12 23:41  123
```

In the above data-set power consumed by an appliance in 6th sec of every minute is given.I want to convert the data-set to 1 hour time series with Power Unit=KW/h i.e. I want to convert it to power consumed in an hour without summing every 6th sec power consumption.

I tired to sum them after multiplying 6th sec power consumption with 2.77778e-7 but I get the feeling i am doing it wrong. Is it the right way to do it? If not What is the right Way?

I used the following code for summing them up.

```
    data = pd.read_csv(
    r'E:\ukdale\house_1\channel_6.dat',
    delimiter=' ',
    header=None,
    names=['Date', 'Power'],
    dtype={'Date': np.int64, 'Power': np.float64},
    index_col='Date'
    )
    data.index = pd.to_datetime((data.index.values), unit='s')
    ts = pd.Series(data=data['Power'])
    ts.multiply(0.000000277778)
    ts1=ts.resample('h').sum()
    ts1.dropna(inplace=True)
```

My results:

```
Dates           Power(KW/h)
09-11-12 22:00  310
09-11-12 23:00  64948
10-11-12 0:00   279706
10-11-12 1:00   386517
10-11-12 2:00   0
10-11-12 3:00   125
10-11-12 4:00   0
10-11-12 5:00   0
10-11-12 6:00   0
10-11-12 7:00   0
10-11-12 8:00   95
10-11-12 9:00   582
10-11-12 10:00  594
10-11-12 11:00  585
```

Answer (score 0):

You can round the time values to the nearest hour and then sum them:

```
# Round the Timestamp to the nearest 60 minutes
scalefactor <- 60
data$Dates <- as.POSIXlt(round(as.numeric(data$Dates)/scalefactor) * scalefactor,
                                                                     origin="1970-01-01")
```